# Cucumber: How to write definition steps in Ruby Capybara

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, capybara

I am new to cucumber and have the simplest setup of cucumber/ruby/capybara/selenium driver.

I have a scenario outline such as:

```
Feature: Country of user is displayed
Scenario Outline: CountryCode of User is displayed based on his Country selected.
Given the user is on the test page
When I select my "<Country>" 
And the testpage is loaded
Then the "<CountryCode>" is displayed

Examples:
 | Country       | CountryCode |
 | Canada        | CA          |
 | United States | US          |
```

step Definition:

```
 Given(/^the user is on the test page$/) do
 visit 'http://....'
end

When(/^I select my "([^"]*)"$/) do |table|
 select([Country], :from => 'id-of-dropdown')
 click_on('Submit')
end

When(/^the testpage is loaded$/) do
 pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

Then(/^the "([^"]*)" from UserSetLocation is displayed$/) do |arg1|
 pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
```

my env.rb file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'rspec'

Capybara.run_server = false
#Set default driver as Selenium
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
#Set default driver as webkit (browserless)
#Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
#Set default selector as css
Capybara.default_selector = :css

#Syncronization related settings
module Helpers
 def without_resynchronize
  page.driver.options[:resynchronize] = false
  yield
  page.driver.options[:resynchronize] = true
 end
end
World(Capybara::DSL, Helpers)
```

The issue I have is what is the correct syntax to pull the value from the datatable, country column for:

```
When(/^I enter my "([^"]*)"$/) do |table|
   select([Country], :from => 'id-of-dropdown')
```

the following works, but I don't want to write this same step for every country, that datatable will potentially include dozens of countries.

```
select("Canada", :from => 'id-of-dropdown')
```

I realized perhaps my env.rb is missing info or I am simply not using the right syntax?
I have literally been searching online and on this site for days, and any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you for your time.
Melie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using scenario outlines, the table values are passed to the step definition. It is not the table that is passed. The step:

```
When I select my "<Country>"
```

Is conceptually the same as:

```
When I select my "Canada"
```

and

```
When I select my "United States"
```

In the step definition, `table` is the captured value between the quotations. You can see that it is just a `String`.

```
When(/^I select my "([^"]*)"$/) do |table|
  p table.class
  #=> String

  p table
  #=> "Canada" or "United States"
end
```

You can pass this value straight to the `select` method. You probably want to rename the variable to be reflect its value:

```
When(/^I select my "([^"]*)"$/) do |country|
  select(country, :from => 'id-of-dropdown')
  click_on('Submit')
end
```

Comment: Thank you Justin for the quick explanation and solution, it works now! I have much to learn for sure.